# How to pass vector's cell to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, pass-by-reference

I want to make a function that takes an object from a vector's cell and modifies it. First I need to pass this cell by reference to the function and I can not do it.

```
void circleChoiceOne(Circle& object);
vector<Shape*> shapeArr;
int main()
{
    circleChoiceOne(shapeArr[choice]);
    return 0;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

The error I get is pointed to line 7 and it says:
A reference of type `Circle &` cannot be initialized with a value of type `Shape *`.

Answer (score 3):

`shapeArr[choice]` will return a `Shape*` but the method expects a `Circle&`.

I'm assuming that `Circle` is a subclass of `Shape`.

You will need a `dynamic_cast` to downcast the `Shape*` to a `Circle*`, then you'll want to dereference the pointer to a value so you can pass it by-reference.

You will need to verify that the `Shape*` actually points to a `Circle` (as opposed to a `Rectangle` or `Torus`) before casting and handle the case when it doesn't.

Comment: I am trying dynamic casting:
"shapeArr[choice] = dynamic_cast<Shape*>(*Circle);"
But it says on "Circle" - type name not allowed.

Comment: @YazenVid Your question, and my answer, concerns accessing an element from your `vector`, not assigning to it. Also that code in your comment won't compile because `Circle` is a type, not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can not initialize reference with a pointer (unless it is a reference to a pointer, of course) - exactly what compiler is saying. Either change the function signature to accept pointer, or call the function with a dereferenced object, or store `std::ref` in the container. This is in assumption that `Shape` is a descendant of `Circle` (which is slightly bizzare).

Example:

```
void circleChoiceOne(Circle* object);
```

Or

```
circleChoiceOne(*shapeArr[choice]);
```

Or

```
vector<std::ref<Shape>> shapeArr;
```

Comment: It does not work, it says: "no suitable conversion function from "Shape" to "Circle *" exists